# LLVM C++ API How to create a constant f128

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

how can I create a constant f128 (quad) using the LLVM C*+ API.
Usually you do it like this (as per the tutorial):

```
ConstantFP::get(*TheContext, APFloat(Val))
```

But APFloat has no constructor that can take a long double or a StringRef where I can pass in the string repr of the quad.
So how do I create a long double with the LLVM C++ API? As per the documentation of the IR language I know that a f128 type exists.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like APFloat has a [constructor that takes a String](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html#a271da21b4c6619b24fcdb30bc6c82ed1) and [another](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html#afd147a3ee2d7379f47b9197c2ce2f912) that takes an abitrary precision integer (presumably containing the bits of the IEEE754 representation). The `fp128` Type object has [`getFltSemantics()`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#adc21598ac33ea9d50f3a939f26a28940) which both constructors need.

Comment: I will try the first constructor that takes a string and report back, if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this method](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantFP.html#a5eb8f7a5d3cfdd127ad9db2e425e14eb) instead with an f128 type gotten from [this llvm::Type static member](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#a49f37835a410e050b960dd936a54dd05)